# C# Socket constructor invalid arguments

Tags: c#, sockets, constructor

This line of code has been working for a long time. Compiles OK, but at runtime I get 'An invalid argument was supplied'

```
listner = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

As they are all standard constants it's difficult to imagine what could be wrong.

Ideas anybody?

(BTW, I rewrote the line using Intellisense just to make sure the constants were correct).

Comment: that line is fine on regular .NET on Windows; are you perhaps on an exotic platform? are you very very sure it is *that line* that is failing? what is the `.StackTrace` of the exception that happens?

Comment: Are you sure it's that line? It's completely according the specs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: VS13 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If it really fails there, it's something that likely can't be fixed except through liberal applications of `netsh winsock reset`, a reinstall, or telling some excessive antimalware/user firewall software to back off. Also, be sure to try the line in LINQPad to exclude trouble with your build process/targeted binaries.

Comment: This is from the stack trace, it really is in sys.net.socks contructor……….at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at BackEnd.backEnd..ctor(String config) in

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct namespace? I would try giving the full path just to make sure: System.Net.Sockets.Socket(...)

Comment: Using windows defender. Code has of course been completely cleaned and recompiled.

Comment: During a Windows update my IPv4 interface was shutdown leaving only IPV6 on. Maybe it's your case

Comment: IP4 enabled, IP6 disabled.

Comment: Thing is, that code almost cannot fail unless the Winsock config is completely hosed, some DLL has injected itself and is actively interfering with the `WSASocket` call or the JIT compiler bugged out (either with your code or with the native framework images); there's very little room for trouble there. You could try a simple C program that directly invokes `WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)` and check the return value to further narrow things down.

Comment: After tests on multiple sites I'm coming to the conclusion that the problem may be upgrade related. Perhaps MS have depreciated TCP stream without telling anybody :D